# Apps to call cabs/taxis in Germany for non-German speakers

Tags: germany, transportation, taxis, language-barrier, german-language

I will be travelling to Germany next week. I don't speak German, only Portuguese and English.

Are there mobile apps for me to call taxis in Germany (Frankfurt) in English, such as 99 and easy taxi?

I will also be in Seligenstadt for some days probably, and my hotel is in Obertshausen.

How about uber?

I am with an iPhone 4

Comment: English works fine with taxi services in Frankfurt. Additionally, you only need one or two contact numbers if you are staying within the [FFM  conurbation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankfurt_Rhine-Main).

Comment: I should go to Seligenstadt too. I guess is a small city. What about that?

Comment: Seligenstadt is further out and not really as taxi-friendly as the locales closer in, plan ahead for that one.  Taxi.de has [the app](http://www.taxi.de/) you are looking for though.  There is an online version at the same link.  You may be able to 'infer' how to fill out the order entry form without too much knowledge of German (e.g., Handynummer = mobile number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankfurt is massively cosmopolitan and its taxi services are generally ready to work with you in English.  This would hold true for locales extending north to the Taunus.  Generally you would only need to carry one or two numbers anyway.

You mentioned Seligenstadt and Obertshausen, the former being further out and not a sure bet unless you plan ahead.  Obertshausen is comfortably within reach.

There is a [downloadable app at taxi.de](http://www.taxi.de/) which operates on a national basis.  The same site offers a web based order entry form which you may find more helpful. Unfortunately this app is only available in German.

Answer (score 0):

The [taxi.eu](http://www.taxi.eu) app works in Germany and is localized.

Answer (score 0):

[mytaxi](https://us.mytaxi.com/index.html) works pretty well in all larger cities I've tested so far. There definitely is an English version and I like the app's design, e.g. the fact that you can see the current position of the driver and know when to step out of the door.